# Smaller gallery carousel on landscape mode phone

Tags: html, css

When I view my website in portrait mode, the gallery looks good, but when I view it in landscape mode, it's enormous. On my iPhone SE it's even too big for the screen.
I don't know how I can get it smaller. Could someone help me?
Url: http://st358373.cmd16c.cmi.hanze.nl/aljen/home/

```
@media screen and (max-width: 736px) {
    #galery-carousel {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
    .carousel.slide {
        width: 100% !important;

    }}
```

Desktop:

```
.galerij-slider {
  width: 60% !important;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

The mobile CSS doesn't pick up the div for galerij-slider. I hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the media queries of the iphone. [Source](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/).

**Ex:-**

You can have it like this.

**iPhone 5 & 5S in portrait & landscape**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

**iPhone 5 & 5S in landscape**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

**iPhone 5 & 5S in portrait**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

Have your styles inside the media queries.

**Ex:-**

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 568px) {
          #content {
            float: none;
            width: 100%;
          }
          #navigation {
            float: none;
            width: auto;
          }
        }
```

Comment: I know, but I still can't get it right, because when I have the width on 60% the content spills out.

Comment: Which content spills out? did u try with the widths i have recommended? also did u try with `vw` for the width?